# What is correct by common sense: (int) blabla * 255.99999999999997 or round(blabla*255)?

Tags: c++, c, casting, rounding, floor

Recently I found this interesting thing in webkit sources, related to color conversions (hsl to rgb):

http://osxr.org/android/source/external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/Color.cpp#0111

```
const double scaleFactor = nextafter(256.0, 0.0); // it's here something like 255.99999999999997
// .. some code skipped
return makeRGBA(static_cast<int>(calcSomethingFrom0To1(blablabla) * scaleFactor),
```

Same I found here: http://www.filewatcher.com/p/kdegraphics-4.6.0.tar.bz2.5101406/kdegraphics-4.6.0/kolourpaint/imagelib/effects/kpEffectHSV.cpp.html

```
(int)(value * 255.999999)
```

Is it correct to use such technique at all? Why dont' use something straight like round(blabla * 255)?
Is it features of C/C++? As I see strictly speaking is will return not always correct results, in 27 cases of 100. See spreadsheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AbGnRgSp_5FCKAeNrELPJ5j9zON9HLiHoHC870PwdMc/edit?usp=sharing

Somebody pls explain — I think it should be something basic.

Comment: You might be forgetting about rounding error, there MAY be cases where multiplication in the floating point realm could return a value that if rounded after, could be higher or lower than a pre-rounded case.

Comment: One truncates and one rounds - which is correct depends on what was intended, which is not clear.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's a great article and all, but no one *actually* reads it, and it's not particularly relevant here.

Comment: @Cornstalks I agree it's not relevant for the particular behavior in question.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Well, it is somewhat relevant for _"Is this correct?"_ because it isn't in the general case. Incidentially, there's no difference in that color conversion code since color values range from 0.0 to 1.0. But if one may assume that in principle the inputs could be _any_ value, the multiplication trick is just wrong since it accidentially works or doesn't work, depending on what values you use it with.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Normally we want to map a real value `x` in the (closed) interval `[0,1]`  to an integer value `j` in the range `[0 ...255]`.

And we want to do it in a "fair" way, so that, if the reals are uniformly distributed in the range, the discrete values will be approximately equiprobable: each of the 256 discrete values should get "the same share" (1/256) from the `[0,1]` interval. That is, we want a mapping like this:

```
[0    , 1/256) -> 0
[1/256, 2/256) -> 1 
...
[254/256, 255/256) -> 254
[255/256, 1]       -> 255
```

We are not much concerned about the transition points [*], but we do want to cover the full the range [0,1]. How to accomplish that?

If we simply do `j = (int)(x *255)`: the value 255 would almost never appear (only when `x=1`); and the rest of the values `0...254` would each get a share of 1/255 of the interval. This would be unfair, *regardless* of the rounding behaviour at the limit points.

If we instead do `j = (int)(x * 256)`: this partition would be fair, except for a sngle problem: we would get the value 256 (out of range!) when `x=1` [**]

That's why `j = (int)(x * 255.9999...)` (where `255.9999...` is actually the largest double less than 256) will do.

An alternative implementation (also reasonable, almost equivalent) would be

```
j = (int)(x * 256); 
if(j == 256)  j = 255;  
// j = x == 1.0 ? 255 : (int)(x * 256); // alternative
```

but this would be more clumsy and probably less efficient.

`round()` does not help here. For example, `j = (int)round(x * 255)` would give a 1/255 share to the integers `j=1...254` and half that value to the extreme points `j=0`, `j=255`.

[image]

[*] I mean: we are not extremely interested in what happens in the 'small' neighbourhood of, say, 3/256: rounding might give 2 or 3, it doesn't matter. But we are interested in the extrema: we want to get 0 and 255, for `x=0` and `x=1`respectively.

[**] The IEEE floating point standard guarantees that there's no rounding ambiguity here: integers admit an exact floating point representation, the product will be exact, and the casting will give always 256. Further, we are guaranteed that `1.0 * z = z`.

Comment: +1 for that beautiful graphic. (sidenote: may I ask what you used to make it?)

Comment: @Cornstalks : nothing fanciful, mere Paint.NET :-)

Comment: @Ah, the good old "made by hand" tactic, eh? I was thinking you may have done something along the lines of [xkcd/974](https://xkcd.com/974/) or [xkcd/1319](https://xkcd.com/1319/).

Comment: Thank you! In justice we trust.

Answer (score 7):

In general, I'd say `(int)(blabla * 255.99999999999997)` is more correct than using `round()`.

Why?

Because with `round()`, 0 and 255 only have "half" the range that 1-254 do. If you `round()`, then 0-0.00196078431 get mapped to 0, while 0.00196078431-0.00588235293 get mapped to 1. This means that 1 has 200% more probability of occurring than 0, which is, strictly speaking, an unfair bias.

If, isntead, one multiplies by 255.99999999999997 and then floors (which is what casting to an integer does, since it truncates), then each integer from 0 to 255 are equally likely.

Your spreadsheet might show this better if it counted in fractional percentages (i.e. if it counted by 0.01% instead of 1% each time). [I've made a simple spreadsheet to show this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhWx_dIBnyRodHQwZU1UZHoxNEdwaUFRVkVIdlBYdWc&usp=sharing). If you look at that spreadsheet, you'll see that 0 is unfairly biased against when `round()`ing, but with the other method things are fair and equal.

Answer (score 5):

Casting to int has the same effect as the floor function (i.e. it truncates). When you call round it, well, rounds to the nearest integer.

They do different things, so choose the one you need.

Comment: So why would webkit choose the unintuitive `(int)(value * 255.999999)` over the more intuitive `round(value * 255)`?

Comment: @MooingDuck, my guess is as bad as yours. You'd have to ask whoever wrote the program.