# > REQ Swift refactor / code layout / review

Tags: swift

I have made a mess of my translation from Obj-C to Swift so I'd really appreciate a refactor/code layout review. The curly braces are really throwing me. Are there any Xcode plugins or something to help me better manage my code blocks?

Some of my functions and calculations may not be so efficient as well so if you have any suggestions for those areas that would be great too. For example if you have used or seen better filter algorithms etc.

p.s. thanks Martin.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia
import CoreVideo

let minFramesForFilterToSettle = 10


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
// If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

var validFrameCounter: Int = 0
var detector: Detector!
var filter: Filter!
// var currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling       // Is this initialized correctly?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.detector = Detector()
    self.filter = Filter()
    // startCameraCapture() // call to un-used function.

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    //println("Capture device found")
                    beginSession()
                }
            }
        }
    }


} // end of viewDidLoad ???



// configure device for camera and focus mode // maybe not needed since we dont use focuc?
func configureDevice() {
    if let device = captureDevice {
        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        //device.focusMode = .Locked
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }

}


// start capturing frames
func beginSession() {
    // Create the AVCapture Session

    configureDevice()

    var err : NSError? = nil
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Automatic Switch ON torch mode
    if  captureDevice!.hasTorch {
        // lock your device for configuration
        captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        // check if your torchMode is on or off. If on turns it off otherwise turns it on
        captureDevice!.torchMode = captureDevice!.torchActive ? AVCaptureTorchMode.Off : AVCaptureTorchMode.On
        // sets the torch intensity to 100%
        captureDevice!.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        // unlock your device
        captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
    }

    // Create a AVCaptureInput with the camera device
    var deviceInput : AVCaptureInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: &err) as! AVCaptureInput
    if deviceInput == nil! {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Set the output
    var videoOutput : AVCaptureVideoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    // create a queue to run the capture on
    var captureQueue : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("captureQueue", nil)

    // setup ourself up as the capture delegate
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureQueue)

    // configure the pixel format
    videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] // kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey is a CFString btw.

    // set the minimum acceptable frame rate to 10 fps
    captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 10)

    // and the size of the frames we want - we'll use the smallest frame size available
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow

    // Add the input and output
    captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
    captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)


    // Start the session
    captureSession.startRunning()

    // we're now sampling from the camera
    enum CurrentState {
        case statePaused
        case stateSampling
        }
    var currentState = CurrentState.statePaused

    func setState(state: CurrentState){
        switch state
        {
        case .statePaused:
            // what goes here? Something like this?
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = false
        case .stateSampling:
            // what goes here? Something like this?
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true  // singletons

        }
    }

    // we're now sampling from the camera
    currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling


    // stop the app from sleeping
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true

    // update our UI on a timer every 0.1 seconds
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    func stopCameraCapture() {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil
    }


    // pragma mark Pause and Resume of detection
     func pause() {
        if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
           return
        }

        // switch off the torch
        if captureDevice!.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            captureDevice!.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
            captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
    currentState = CurrentState.statePaused
    // let the application go to sleep if the phone is idle
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = false
    }


    func resume() {
        if currentState != CurrentState.statePaused {
            return
        }

        // switch on the torch
        if captureDevice!.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            captureDevice!.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.On
            captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
    currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling
    // stop the app from sleeping
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
    }

    // beginning of paste

    // r,g,b values are from 0 to 1 // h = [0,360], s = [0,1], v = [0,1]
    //  if s == 0, then h = -1 (undefined)
   func RGBtoHSV(r : Float, g : Float, b : Float, inout h : Float, inout s : Float, inout v : Float) {
        let rgbMin = min(r, g, b)
        let rgbMax = max(r, g, b)
        let delta = rgbMax - rgbMin

        v = rgbMax
        s = delta/rgbMax
        h = Float(0.0) 



    // start of calculation
        if (rgbMax != 0) {
            s = delta / rgbMax
        }
        else{
            // r = g = b = 0
            s = 0    
            h = -1
            return
        }

        if r == rgbMax {
            h = (g - b) / delta
        }
        else if (g == rgbMax) {
            h = 2 + (b - r ) / delta
        }
        else{
            h = 4 + (r - g) / delta
            h = 60
        }
        if (h < 0) {
            h += 360
        }
    }



        // process the frame of video
    func captureOutput(captureOutput:AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer, fromConnection connection:AVCaptureConnection) {
        // if we're paused don't do anything
        if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
            // reset our frame counter
            self.validFrameCounter = 0

            return
        }

    // this is the image buffer
    var cvimgRef:CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvimgRef, 0)
    // access the data
    var width: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvimgRef)
    var height:size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvimgRef)
    // get the raw image bytes
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef))
    var bprow: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvimgRef)


    var r = 0
    var g = 0
    var b = 0

        for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
            for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {
                b+=buf[x](UnsafeMutablePointer(UInt8))  // fix
                g+=buf[x + 1](UnsafeMutablePointer(Float)) // fix 
                r+=buf[x + 2](UnsafeMutablePointer(Int)) // fix
            }
            buf += bprow()
        }
        r /= 255 * (width*height)
        g /= 255 * (width*height)
        b /= 255 * (width*height)


    }


    // convert from rgb to hsv colourspace
    var h = Float()
    var s = Float()
    var v = Float()

    RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v)

    // do a sanity check for blackness
    if s > 0.5 && v > 0.5 {
        // increment the valid frame count 
        validFrameCounter++
        // filter the hue value - the filter is a simple band pass filter that removes any DC component and any high frequency noise
        var filtered: Float = filter.processValue(h)
        // have we collected enough frames for the filter to settle?
        if validFrameCounter > minFramesForFilterToSettle {
            // add the new value to the detector
            detector.addNewValue(filtered, atTime: CACurrentMediaTime())
        }
    } else {
        validFrameCounter = 0
        // clear the detector - we only really need to do this once, just before we start adding valid samples
        detector.reset()
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v)`, as I suggested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29808914/1187415) to your previous question?

Comment: It doesn't work is a bad problem description. Does it not compile? (What are the error messages?) Or does it not give the expected result? (What result do you get and what do you expect)? – Note that defining *local variables* r, g, b, h, s, v *inside* `RGBtoHSV()` makes no sense at all and hides the function parameters. Perhaps that is your problem.

Comment: The code that I suggested in my answer to your previous question does compile and does work as expected. But you copied `let r : Float = 0.3 ... var v : Float = 0.0` *into* that function and that does not make sense.

Comment: Now you have changed to a completely different question, but *"I'd really appreciate a code layout review and clean up."* is far too broad for SO and *"How do you guys keep track of so many curly braces with all the loops and all? "* is not a real question and/or primarily opinion based.

Comment: Ok so what is the proper terminology you senior programmers use?  Am I supposed to use 'refactoring' or something in my question? I realized from your function comment that my code is a mess so I would really like a review/layout/refactor check.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that

```
RGBtoHSV(r: r, g: g, b: b, h: &h, s: &s, v: &v)
```

Comment: No. Free functions don't take argument labels by default.

Comment: Martin. I updated and cleaned. I edited my question asking for a layout review. Please see above. Thank you.