# How to convert UIColor to string and string to UIColor using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have an object with a UIColor property:

```
class Beer: NSObject {
  var color: UIColor?
  ...
}
```

I'm saving this to a DB, so I need to make this property into a valid JSON type, so I'm thinking of converting it to a string. How can I convert into a string to store, and then when loading using that string to create the UIColor?

Comment: you can convert the UIColor into Hex color code then store it in the DB and use can use that code directly at retrieval or convert it into UIColor

Comment: Best to store the rgb and alpha components as float values. Check this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835093/storing-uicolor-object-in-core-data

Comment: would either of you mind writing a full answer?

Answer (score 17):

I have put some sample for both conversion, still you can find many code for the conversion

For the conversion from UIColor to hex string you can use the following code:

```
extension UIColor {
    var rgbComponents:(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        if getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a) {
            return (r,g,b,a)
        }
        return (0,0,0,0)
    }
    // hue, saturation, brightness and alpha components from UIColor**
    var hsbComponents:(hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, brightness: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var hue:CGFloat = 0
        var saturation:CGFloat = 0
        var brightness:CGFloat = 0
        var alpha:CGFloat = 0
        if getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha){
            return (hue,saturation,brightness,alpha)
        }
        return (0,0,0,0)
    }
    var htmlRGBColor:String {
        return String(format: "#%02x%02x%02x", Int(rgbComponents.red * 255), Int(rgbComponents.green * 255),Int(rgbComponents.blue * 255))
    }
    var htmlRGBaColor:String {
        return String(format: "#%02x%02x%02x%02x", Int(rgbComponents.red * 255), Int(rgbComponents.green * 255),Int(rgbComponents.blue * 255),Int(rgbComponents.alpha * 255) )
    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
let myColorBlack = UIColor.blackColor().webColor         //#000000ff
let myLghtGrayColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().webColor  //#aaaaaaff
let myDarkGrayColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().webColor
```

For more info you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28697136/4557505
https://gist.github.com/yannickl/16f0ed38f0698d9a8ae7

You can store this string inside the db and retrieve it when you need it

From HexString to UIColor

```
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hexString: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
            let hexColor = hexString.substringFromIndex(start)

            if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
                let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:UIColor(hexString: "#ffe700ff")

Ref: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor
https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift 
https://gist.github.com/arshad/de147c42d7b3063ef7bc

Comment: It seems this isn't precise. My color is `#EAEDFF`, but `color.htmlRGBColor` equals `#EAECFE`.

Comment: Sorry for off-site link, but this one seems to be precise: https://cocoacasts.com/from-hex-to-uicolor-and-back-in-swift

Answer (score 5):

Here is an update for:

1. **Swift 5.0**
2. combination for **UIKit**-n-**SwiftUI** architecture
3. #RRGGBBAA / #RRGGBB color values

__

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

extension Color {

    init?(hexString: String) {

        let rgbaData = getrgbaData(hexString: hexString)

        if(rgbaData != nil){

            self.init(
                        .sRGB,
                        red:     Double(rgbaData!.r),
                        green:   Double(rgbaData!.g),
                        blue:    Double(rgbaData!.b),
                        opacity: Double(rgbaData!.a)
                    )
            return
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    public convenience init?(hexString: String) {

        let rgbaData = getrgbaData(hexString: hexString)

        if(rgbaData != nil){
            self.init(
                        red:   rgbaData!.r,
                        green: rgbaData!.g,
                        blue:  rgbaData!.b,
                        alpha: rgbaData!.a)
            return
        }
        return nil
    }
}

private func getrgbaData(hexString: String) -> (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat)? {

    var rgbaData : (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat)? = nil

    if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {

        let start = hexString.index(hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let hexColor = String(hexString[start...]) // Swift 4

        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

        if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {

            rgbaData = { // start of a closure expression that returns a Vehicle
                switch hexColor.count {
                case 8:

                    return ( r: CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255,
                             g: CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255,
                             b: CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8)  / 255,
                             a: CGFloat( hexNumber & 0x000000ff)        / 255
                           )
                case 6:

                    return ( r: CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255,
                             g: CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff00) >> 8)  / 255,
                             b: CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff))       / 255,
                             a: 1.0
                           )
                default:
                    return nil
                }
            }()

        }
    }

    return rgbaData
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A little shorter using NSCoding:

```
public extension UIColor{

    var codedString: String?{
        do{
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: true)

            return data.base64EncodedString()

        }
        catch let error{
            print("Error converting color to coded string: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }


    static func color(withCodedString string: String) -> UIColor?{
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: string) else{
            return nil
        }

        return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data)

    }
}
```

Comment: This approach proved to be much more reliable for me than the other solutions proposed here, as some colors were not properly converted with the other methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @HardikDG code, these are simple Objective C functions:

```
- (NSString *) colorToString:(UIColor *) color {
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x%02x", (int)(red * 255), (int)(green * 255), (int)(blue * 255), (int)(alpha * 255)];
}

- (UIColor *) stringToColor:(NSString *) color {
    if([color length] != 8) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:color];
    UInt64 hexNumber = 0;
    if ([scanner scanHexLongLong:&hexNumber]) {
        CGFloat r = ((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255.0;
        CGFloat g = ((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255.0;
        CGFloat b = ((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255.0;
        CGFloat a = (hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255.0;

        return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
    }

    return [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I add my own extension, hope you appreciate:

```
extension UIColor {

    func toRGBAString(uppercased: Bool = true) -> String {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let rgba = [r, g, b, a].map { $0 * 255 }.reduce("", { $0 + String(format: "%02x", Int($1)) })
        return uppercased ? rgba.uppercased() : rgba
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
func returnUIColor(components: String) -> UIColor {
    let scanner = Scanner(string: components)
    let skipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[], ")
    let comma = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",")
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = skipped

    var r, g, b, a : NSString?

    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &r)
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &g)
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &b)
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &a)

    let defaultColor = UIColor.lightGray

    guard let rUnwrapped = r else { return defaultColor }
    guard let gUnwrapped = g else { return defaultColor }
    guard let bUnwrapped = b else { return defaultColor }
    guard let aUnwrapped = a else { return defaultColor }

    let rfloat = CGFloat(rUnwrapped.doubleValue)
    let gfloat = CGFloat(gUnwrapped.doubleValue)
    let bfloat = CGFloat(bUnwrapped.doubleValue)
    let afloat = CGFloat(aUnwrapped.doubleValue)

    let newUIColor = UIColor(red: rfloat, green: gfloat, blue: bfloat, alpha: afloat)
    return newUIColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 IOS 10.x 
Don't understand why this is so complicated, this works... I must have missed something... read it carefully, start with item 1 not 0.

```
 // convert color to string
 let color = userInfo["color"] as! UIColor       
 let diyColor = String(describing: color)

 // convert string back to color
 let diyValues = diyColor.components(separatedBy: " ")
 print("diyValues \(diyValues)")
        let returnedColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: diyValues[1].FloatValue()!, green: diyValues[2].FloatValue()!, blue: diyValues[3].FloatValue()!, alpha: diyValues[4].FloatValue()!)
```

Using this extension too...

```
extension String {

func FloatValue() -> Float? {
    guard let doubleValue = Double(self) else {
        return nil
    }

    return Float(doubleValue)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below UIColor extension to convert String to Color and vice versa.

```
extension UIColor {


//Convert RGBA String to UIColor object
//"rgbaString" must be separated by space "0.5 0.6 0.7 1.0" 50% of Red 60% of Green 70% of Blue Alpha 100%
public convenience init?(rgbaString : String){
    self.init(ciColor: CIColor(string: rgbaString))
}

//Convert UIColor to RGBA String
func toRGBAString()-> String {

    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var b: CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return "\(r) \(g) \(b) \(a)"

}
//return UIColor from Hexadecimal Color string
public convenience init?(hexaDecimalString: String) {

        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hexaDecimalString.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hexaDecimalString.index(hexaDecimalString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hexColor = hexaDecimalString.substring(from: start)

            if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
                let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
// Convert UIColor to Hexadecimal String
func toHexString() -> String {
    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var b: CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return String(
        format: "%02X%02X%02X",
        Int(r * 0xff),
        Int(g * 0xff),
        Int(b * 0xff)
    )
}
```

}

Save this color string(`stringWhite`) in to DataBase

```
let stringWhite =  UIColor.white.toHexString()
```

when reading color string from DataBase use below code to convert `stringWhite` to UIColor

```
let whiteColor = UIColor(hexaDecimalString: stringWhite)
```

Comment: Like very many other answers that this seems copied from, you are not supporting alpha values, despite getting the alpha value during the computation.