# Use Hex color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uicolor

In UIKit we could use an Extension to set hex color to almost everything, like in this [tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor). But when I'm trying to do it in SwiftUI, it's not possible, it looks like the SwiftUI does not get the `UIColor` as parameter.

```
Text(text)
    .color(UIColor.init(hex: "FFF"))
```

Error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UIColor' to expected argument type 'Color?'
```

I even tried to make an extension for `Color`, instead of `UIColor`, but I haven't any luck.

My extension for `Color`:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 0
        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
        
        let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
        let b = rgbValue & 0xff
        
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
            green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
            blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
        )
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'red:green:blue:alpha:', expected '_:red:green:blue:opacity:')
```

Comment: The init is this one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/3265484-init It's missing a parameter, as you can see it in your error message: `'red:green:blue:alpha:'` vs `'_:red:green:blue:opacity:`, see the `_:` at the start which is for the `_ colorSpace:` and `opacity` vs `alpha`.

Comment: @Larme yes I tried that, it fixed the compile error, but nothing in result, it does not set the color to the view, did you solve it for yourself? If you do please add the code.

Comment: Actually, SwiftUI **does** get the `UIColor` as a parameter like `Color(uiColor: ...)`. More info at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994667/5623035)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You're almost there, you were using the wrong initialiser parameter:

```swift
extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (a, r, g, b) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        }

        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double(r) / 255,
            green: Double(g) / 255,
            blue:  Double(b) / 255,
            opacity: Double(a) / 255
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: it solved the compile error, thanks, but it did not set the color the views in SwiftUI, no error but no result

Comment: I tried with Color("ff00ff") and worked fine. What are you passing as hex?

Comment: Please also indicate what color do you get for a specific hex parameter.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for '#hexColorStr'. Please use my one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341358/how-to-convert-uicolor-to-string-and-string-to-uicolor-using-swift#answer-62192394

Comment: This fails: `XCTAssertEqual(Color(hex: "0xFFFFFF"), Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255))`. along with "ffffff" and "FFFFFF"

Comment: `XCTAssertEqual(Color(hex: 0xFFFFFF), Color(red: 255 / 255, green: 255 / 255, blue: 255 / 255))`  or `XCTAssertEqual(Color(hex: 0xFFFFFF), Color(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1))`  will succeed

Answer (score 87):

Another alternative below that uses Int for hex but of course, it can be changed to String if you prefer that.

```
extension Color {
    init(hex: UInt, alpha: Double = 1) {
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            green: Double((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            blue: Double((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
            opacity: alpha
        )
    }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
Color(hex: 0x000000)
Color(hex: 0x000000, alpha: 0.2)
```

Comment: That's a good implementation! How would you use String instead of Int?

Comment: For anyone interested, this approach is explained (in a general context not related to SwiftUI) in The Swift Programming Language book, in [Advanced Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#). The whole chapter is worth reading. TIP: The key to understanding is the right shift and bitwise AND, and the simplest examples are 1. halving a number using right shift (number >> 1) and 2. checking whether the number  odd (number & 0x1 == 1).The [Bitwise_operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) Wikipedia article is worth reading as well.

Comment: Why did you create a tuple only to extract all of its values in the very next statement? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PeterSchorn yeah makes sense, I removed the tuple. Thanks!

Comment: @TolgahanArıkan No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: This test fails:  `XCTAssertEqual(Color(hex: 0xffffff), Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255))`

Comment: @ScottyBlades this is because Color(red: green: blue:) expects values between 0 and 1, where 0 represents 0x00 and 1 represents 0xFF and anything in between is a fraction of that.  Change your test to `XCTAssertEqual(Color(hex: 0xFFFFFF), Color(red: 255 / 255, green: 255 / 255, blue: 255 / 255))
` or `XCTAssertEqual(Color(hex: 0xFFFFFF), Color(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1))` and your test will succeed.

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

```
extension Color {
    init(hex: Int, opacity: Double = 1.0) {
        let red = Double((hex & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = Double((hex & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = Double((hex & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0
        self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: opacity)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("Hello World!")
    .background(Color(hex: 0xf5bc53))

Text("Hello World!")
    .background(Color(hex: 0xf5bc53, opacity: 0.8))
```

Comment: But slow for compilation :) 9 sec from scratch :)

Comment: @iTux This has nothing to do with compile time. This is a runtime operation. You are probably mixing things up

Answer (score 44):

Here is a Playground with my solution. It adds fallbacks after fallbacks and only relies on the hexString for color and alpha.

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    init(hex string: String) {
        var string: String = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if string.hasPrefix("#") {
            _ = string.removeFirst()
        }

        // Double the last value if incomplete hex
        if !string.count.isMultiple(of: 2), let last = string.last {
            string.append(last)
        }

        // Fix invalid values
        if string.count > 8 {
            string = String(string.prefix(8))
        }

        // Scanner creation
        let scanner = Scanner(string: string)

        var color: UInt64 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&color)

        if string.count == 2 {
            let mask = 0xFF

            let g = Int(color) & mask

            let gray = Double(g) / 255.0

            self.init(.sRGB, red: gray, green: gray, blue: gray, opacity: 1)

        } else if string.count == 4 {
            let mask = 0x00FF

            let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
            let a = Int(color) & mask

            let gray = Double(g) / 255.0
            let alpha = Double(a) / 255.0

            self.init(.sRGB, red: gray, green: gray, blue: gray, opacity: alpha)

        } else if string.count == 6 {
            let mask = 0x0000FF
            let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
            let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
            let b = Int(color) & mask

            let red = Double(r) / 255.0
            let green = Double(g) / 255.0
            let blue = Double(b) / 255.0

            self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: 1)

        } else if string.count == 8 {
            let mask = 0x000000FF
            let r = Int(color >> 24) & mask
            let g = Int(color >> 16) & mask
            let b = Int(color >> 8) & mask
            let a = Int(color) & mask

            let red = Double(r) / 255.0
            let green = Double(g) / 255.0
            let blue = Double(b) / 255.0
            let alpha = Double(a) / 255.0

            self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: alpha)

        } else {
            self.init(.sRGB, red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, opacity: 1)
        }
    }
}

let gray0 = Color(hex: "3f")
let gray1 = Color(hex: "#69")
let gray2 = Color(hex: "#6911")
let gray3 = Color(hex: "fff")
let red = Color(hex: "#FF000044s")
let green = Color(hex: "#00FF00")
let blue0 = Color(hex: "0000FF")
let blue1 = Color(hex: "0000F")
```

For getting the hexString from Color.. well, this is not a public API. 
We still need to rely on UIColor implementations for that.

PS: I saw the components solution below.. but if the API changes in the future, my version is a bit more stable.

Comment: This is the best answer here. If you add opacity as a param, it will be the most completed one.

Comment: Agreed, I've tried numerous solutions and this is the best answer here. I don't know why it's not upvoted more than that. Props @Stefan ! As for the opacity, just chain it like you would normally do in SwiftUI... Color(hex: "#003366").opacity(0.2)

Answer (score 27):

**Best Practice**

This Method is the intended way to set custom colours in the app. Once set, the colours are accessible across all views and are easily updated. It is also **one line of code.**

1. Open your 'Assets' Folder from the left panel where your project files are located

[image: Color Set Example]

2. Now from within the Assets folder, on the left side there should be a '+' button, click that and select 'Color Set'. Once open, rename it to 'Color1'

[image: Color Set Example]

3. Now click the color square in the middle of the page then from the inspector panel on the right, click 'Show Color Panel' selecting your desired color.

[image: Color Set Example]

4. Now go back to your code where you want to change the text color.

   > ```
   > Text
   > .foregroundColor(Color("Color1"))
   > ```

Comment: The problem with this is it is not dynamic. For example, if a user is allowed to choose a color from a pallet, that color likely isn't bundled in the assets that ship with the app.

Answer (score 4):

I also used the solution for `UIColor` by hackingwithswift.
This is an adapted version for `Color`:

```
init?(hex: String) {
    var hexSanitized = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    hexSanitized = hexSanitized.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")

    var rgb: UInt64 = 0

    var red: Double = 0.0
    var green: Double = 0.0
    var blue: Double = 0.0
    var opacity: Double = 1.0

    let length = hexSanitized.count

    guard Scanner(string: hexSanitized).scanHexInt64(&rgb) else { return nil }

    if length == 6 {
        red = Double((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        green = Double((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        blue = Double(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0

    } else if length == 8 {
        red = Double((rgb & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
        green = Double((rgb & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        blue = Double((rgb & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        opacity = Double(rgb & 0x000000FF) / 255.0

    } else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: opacity)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this task, we have to use bitwise Right Shift `>>` operator and bitwise AND `&` operator. Each color channel in a hexadecimal pattern uses 8 bits, or decimal values from 0 to 255, or hexadecimal values from 0x00 to 0xFF.

Bitwise operators are used here to efficiently decompose hexadecimal values ​​by masking and shifting the red component of the color 2 bytes (16 bits) back, and the green component one byte back, respectively. Let's see how it works in Xcode's Live View.

[image]

```
0xFF     == 0x0000FF    // blue
0xFF00   == 0x00FF00    // green
0xFF0077 == 0xFF0077    // pink
```

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    init(_ hexColor: UInt32) {
        self.init(uiColor: .init(
                      red: CGFloat(0xFF & (hexColor >> 0x10)) / 0xFF,
                    green: CGFloat(0xFF & (hexColor >> 0x08)) / 0xFF,
                     blue: CGFloat(0xFF & (hexColor >> 0x00)) / 0xFF,
                    alpha: 1.0))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var hexColor: UInt32 = 0xFF0077    // Deep Pink HEX color
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .foregroundColor(.init(hexColor))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension as

import SwiftUI

```
extension Color {
    init(hex: UInt, alpha: Double = 1) {
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            green: Double((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            blue: Double((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
            opacity: alpha
        )
    }
}
```

How to use

```
 Text("In order to write about life first you must live it")
    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: 0x969696))
```

use 0x before 6 digit hexa value

Answer (score 1):

Head over to "Assers.xcassets" and add a new "Color Set", Click on "Any Apperance - for light mode" or "Dark - for dark mode" and set "Input Method" to 8-bit Hexadecimal and set your HEX code in the hex code. Optionally, you could set a name to this custom color, via the Name field (ex: myCustomColor)and then refer to this color in the UI as "Color(customPurpleColor)"

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
Color(hex: "#FFFFFF") // hashtag + uppercase value
Color(hex: "#ffffff") // hashtag + lowercase value
Color(hex: "FFFFFF") // without hashtag
Color(hex: "FFFFFF", alpha: 0.2) // color value + alpha value
Color(hex: "#0080FF80") // long color & alpha value
```

My solution is based on the code for UIColor, which has performed well in the production environment. [The original code on github](https://gist.github.com/nbasham/3b2de0566d5f716894fc)

```
extension Color {

    init(hex: String?, alpha: CGFloat? = nil) {
        let normalizedHexString: String = Color.normalize(hex)
        var ccc: CUnsignedLongLong = 0
        Scanner(string: normalizedHexString).scanHexInt64(&ccc)
        var resultAlpha: CGFloat {
            switch alpha {
            case nil: return ColorMasks.alphaValue(ccc)
            default: return alpha!
            }
        }
        self.init(CGColor(red: ColorMasks.redValue(ccc),
                          green: ColorMasks.greenValue(ccc),
                          blue: ColorMasks.blueValue(ccc),
                          alpha: resultAlpha))
    }

    func hexDescription(_ includeAlpha: Bool = false) -> String {
        guard let cgColor = self.cgColor else {
            return "Problem with cgColor"
        }
        guard cgColor.numberOfComponents == 4 else {
            return "Color not RGB."
        }
        guard let components = cgColor.components else {
            return "Problem with cgColor.components"
        }
        let aaa = components.map({ Int($0 * CGFloat(255)) })
        let color = String.init(format: "%02x%02x%02x", aaa[0], aaa[1], aaa[2])
        if includeAlpha {
            let alpha = String.init(format: "%02x", aaa[3])
            return "\(color)\(alpha)"
        }
        return color
    }

    fileprivate enum ColorMasks: CUnsignedLongLong {
        case redMask    = 0xff000000
        case greenMask  = 0x00ff0000
        case blueMask   = 0x0000ff00
        case alphaMask  = 0x000000ff

        static func redValue(_ value: CUnsignedLongLong) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat((value & redMask.rawValue) >> 24) / 255.0
        }

        static func greenValue(_ value: CUnsignedLongLong) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat((value & greenMask.rawValue) >> 16) / 255.0
        }

        static func blueValue(_ value: CUnsignedLongLong) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat((value & blueMask.rawValue) >> 8) / 255.0
        }

        static func alphaValue(_ value: CUnsignedLongLong) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(value & alphaMask.rawValue) / 255.0
        }
    }

    fileprivate static func normalize(_ hex: String?) -> String {
        guard var hexString = hex else {
            return "00000000"
        }
        if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
            hexString = String(hexString.dropFirst())
        }
        if hexString.count == 3 || hexString.count == 4 {
            hexString = hexString.map { "\($0)\($0)" } .joined()
        }
        let hasAlpha = hexString.count > 7
        if !hasAlpha {
            hexString += "ff"
        }
        return hexString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on other answers here, especially stefan, my solution is:

````
import SwiftUI
extension Color {
    /**
     Color from  hex string
     
     - Parameter hex: #rrggbbaa hex color (red, green, blue, alpha)
     - Parameter alpha: optional opacity; overrides any hex opacity  present
     - Returns: closest Color match or nil if unrecognizable
     
     The hex string may contain css style shorthand notation as illustrated in the examples.
     ```
     // Example use:
     let color1 = Color(rgb: "#80") // -> #808080ff
     let color2 = Color(rgb: "#abc") // -> #aabbccff
     let color3 = Color(rgb: "abc8") // -> #aabbcc88
     let color4 = Color(rgb: "ffff00") // -> #ffff00ff
     let color5 = Color(rgb: "#808080ff") // #rrggbbaa
     let color6 = Color(rgb: "#12", alpha: 0.5) // -> #12121280
     ```
     */
    init?(rgb hex: String, alpha: Double? = nil) {
        var hexDigits = hex.first == "#" ? String(hex.dropFirst()) : hex
        for digit in hexDigits {
            guard "0123456789abcdefABCDEF".contains(digit) else { return nil }
        }
        if hexDigits.count == 2 { // grayscale
            hexDigits += hexDigits + hexDigits
        }
        if hexDigits.count <= 4 { // #rgb or #rgba
            hexDigits = hexDigits.map { "\($0)\($0)" } .joined(separator: "")
        }
        if hexDigits.count == 6 { // #rrggbb
            hexDigits += "ff"
        }
        // #rrggbbaa
        guard hexDigits.count == 8 else { return nil }
        let digits = Array(hexDigits)
        let rgba = stride(from: 0, to: 8, by: 2).map {
            Double(Int("\(digits[$0])\(digits[$0 + 1])", radix: 16)!) / 255.0
        }
        self = Color(.sRGB, red: rgba[0], green: rgba[1], blue: rgba[2], opacity: alpha ?? rgba[3])
    }
}
````

Answer (score -1):

Usage 
`UIColor.init(hex: "f2000000")`
`UIColor.init(hex: "#f2000000")`
`UIColor.init(hex: "000000")`
`UIColor.init(hex: "#000000")`

```
extension UIColor {
public convenience init(hex:String) {
var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    
    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }
    var r: CGFloat = 0.0
    var g: CGFloat = 0.0
    var b: CGFloat = 0.0
    var a: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
    if ((cString.count) == 8) {
        r = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        g =  CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        b = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x0000FF)) / 255.0
        a = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF000000)  >> 24) / 255.0
        
    }else if ((cString.count) == 6){
        r = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        g =  CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        b = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x0000FF)) / 255.0
        a =  CGFloat(1.0)
    }
    
    
    self.init(  red: r,
                green: g,
                blue: b,
                alpha: a
    )
} }
```

Comment: You are using a UIKit object: UIColor, not a SwiftUI Color.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this extension for **`UIColor`**

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexaString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        let chars = Array(hexaString.dropFirst())
        self.init(red:   .init(strtoul(String(chars[0...1]),nil,16))/255,
                  green: .init(strtoul(String(chars[2...3]),nil,16))/255,
                  blue:  .init(strtoul(String(chars[4...5]),nil,16))/255,
                  alpha: alpha)}
}
```

**`Usage Example:`**

```
let lightGoldColor  = UIColor(hexaString: "#D6CDB2")
```

**`Test Code:`**

[image]

[Resource](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/swift/swiftui+setting+hex+color)

Answer (score -3):

SwiftUI Color creation from hex (3, 4, 6, 8 characters) support for `#`, `alpha`, `web constants`, and `UIColor constants`. Usage examples below.

[Swift Package iOS 14+](https://github.com/nbasham/BlackLabsSwiftUIColor) includes support for `Color` hex, random, CSS colors, and UserDefaults.

[image]

Comment: I don't see `Color(hex:` in the docs nor in code completion.

Comment: @ScottyBlades Sorry about that. If you're using iOS 14 here's a package that will provide Color support for hex and UserDefaults as well. https://github.com/nbasham/BlackLabsSwiftUIColor