# 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Tags: swift, hex, ios13, uicolor

What is alternate of `scanHexInt32` in iOS 13 (Swift 5+)?

```
extension UIColor {


    //--------------------------------------------
    class func hexColor(hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = String(cString[cString.index(cString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)...])
        }

        if (cString.count != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0

// warning in this line - 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```

Ref: Snapshot

[image]

Comment: did you solve this warning?

Comment: Just use **UInt64**. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874327).

Comment: Change line : `Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)`

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I tried that but get this warning - "Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt64>?) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'UInt32'"

Comment: you need to add a check for scanner.isAtEnd

Answer (score 101):

Update to use `UInt64` and `scanHexInt64`:

```
convenience init(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    var hexFormatted: String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if hexFormatted.hasPrefix("#") {
        hexFormatted = String(hexFormatted.dropFirst())
    }

    assert(hexFormatted.count == 6, "Invalid hex code used.")

    var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: hexFormatted).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

    self.init(red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
              blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
              alpha: alpha)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Looks like apple is phasing out Int32 from their 64bit OSs. Try convert your code to use Int64 instead.

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 2.0, deprecated: 13.0)
open func scanHexInt32(_ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?) -> Bool // Optionally prefixed with "0x" or "0X"


@available(iOS 2.0, *)
open func scanHexInt64(_ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt64>?) -> Bool // Optionally prefixed with "0x" or "0X"
```

Answer (score 10):

There is another instance method available:

```swift
scanInt32(representation:)
```

Declaration:

```swift
func scanInt32(representation: Scanner.NumberRepresentation = .decimal) -> Int32?
```

Here, you have to pass the enum value [`.hexadecimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/numberrepresentation?changes=latest_minor).

I hope it will return the same result. The result will be optional.

Comment: I agree. You will notice that `scanInt32(representation:)` is a much newer addition to Scanner and that it does away with the C-style inout parameter and returns an optional, which is the Swifty way. It's obviously meant as a replacement. The compiler's deprecation notice should mention that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this extension swiftui :

```
extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.currentIndex = scanner.string.startIndex
        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

        let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
        let b = rgbValue & 0xff

        self.init(red: Double(r) / 0xff, green: Double(g) / 0xff, blue: Double(b) / 0xff)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using this uicolor extension.. please find the below code

```
extension UIColor {

class func hexColor(hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
} }
```

Comment: this does not account RGBA HEX

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
extension String {

var color: UIColor {
    let hex = trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)

    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        guard let int = Scanner(string: hex).scanInt32(representation: .hexadecimal) else { return #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) }

        let a, r, g, b: Int32
        switch hex.count {
        case 3:     (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)  // RGB (12-bit)
        case 6:     (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)                    // RGB (24-bit)
        case 8:     (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)       // ARGB (32-bit)
        default:    (a, r, g, b) = (255, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255.0)

    } else {
        var int = UInt32()

        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt32
        switch hex.count {
        case 3:     (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)  // RGB (12-bit)
        case 6:     (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)                    // RGB (24-bit)
        case 8:     (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)       // ARGB (32-bit)
        default:    (a, r, g, b) = (255, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255.0)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This combines a couple of the answers, providing both UInt64 and String representations.  It also removes the "convenience" keyword which is unnecessary for Color because it is a struct (whereas it was needed for UIColor since it is a class).  Lastly, it uses Double instead of CGFloat - again, necessary for Color.

```
extension Color
    {
    init(_ hex: UInt64, opacity: Double = 1.0)
        {
        let red = Double((hex & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = Double((hex & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = Double((hex & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0
        self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: opacity)
        }

    init(hex: String, opacity: Double = 1.0)
        {
        // convert the String into an UInt64 and then convert into Color
        var hexFormatted: String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if hexFormatted.hasPrefix("#")
            {
            hexFormatted = String(hexFormatted.dropFirst())
            }

        assert(hexFormatted.count == 6, "Invalid hex code used.")

        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: hexFormatted).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

        self.init(rgbValue, opacity: opacity)
        }
    }
```