# How can I convert SwiftUI Color to either Hex or RGB to save on server

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I want to save SwiftUI Color's (type Color not UIColor) to my server.  To do that I need to convert them to a string.  I think the most convenient would be a Hex String.  I followed the following stack solution to convert a Hex to a SwiftUI color:

[Use Hex color in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874133/use-hex-color-in-swiftui)

but I'm not sure how to go the other way and convert the SwiftUI Color type to a Hex String?

Comment: It is possible to use `Color.cgColor.components`, but I would recommend to keep `Color` as view and `hex` as model, so operate with hex at model/view-model level.

Comment: thanks.  that seems like a much simpler and more sensible way to handle this issue.

Comment: There's a github package that can help, [UIColor-Hex-Swift](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift). Then you can get the hex string like this: `UIColor(color).hexString()` and the other way: `Color(UIColor(hexColor))`

Comment: you could have a look at this SO post/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679658/swift-5-4-hex-to-nscolor/68680901#68680901